# Using the new operator with an object's non-default constructor

Tags: c++

Would something like:

```
classname* p = new classname(parameter1, parameter2, ...);
```

create a pointer that points to an object initialized using a non-default constructor with signature:  `classname(parameter1, parameter2, ...)`?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't answer this question with more than 30 characters. "yes"

Comment: What stopped you  from trying?

Comment: Thanks! Basic question, I know, but I wasn't sure. :D

Comment: @KerrekSB I did try, but I was getting a seg fault in my code and I thought the object might not have been initialized. Checked Google and couldn't find it, so I figured I'd ask here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

---

---

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't have put it better myself - remember to delete it when finished with it though, unless you want to make the heap unhappy!

Comment: Will do. After all, hate to make the heap unhappy. :p

Comment: Indeed, an unhappy heap = an unhappy programmer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will. This program illustrates the concept.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
private:
    std::string name;
public:
    Foo() : name("default"){}
    Foo(std::string Name): name(Name) {}

    void Print() { std::cout << name << std::endl; }
};

int main ()
{
    Foo* foo = new Foo();
    foo->Print();
    delete foo;

    foo = new Foo("special");
    foo->Print();
    delete foo;
}
```

The output is:

```
default
special
```

Comment: Thanks for writing a program to illustrate the concept. You rock! :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. but may I know how did the question came to your mind? you got some errors?